# Log Slow Pages Taking Longer Than [n] Seconds In ColdFusion with Details

Tags: coldfusion, monitoring, coldfusion-9, error-logging, front-controller

(ACF9)

Unless there's an option I'm missing, the "Log Slow Pages Taking Longer Than [n] Seconds" setting isn't useful for front-controller based sites (e.g., Model-Glue, FW/1, Fusebox, Mach-II, etc.).

For instance, in a Mura/Framework-One site, I just end up with:

```
"Warning","jrpp-186","04/25/13","15:26:36",,"Thread: jrpp-186, processing template: /home/mysite/public_html_cms/wwwroot/index.cfm, completed in 11 seconds, exceeding the 10 second warning limit"
"Warning","jrpp-196","04/25/13","15:27:11",,"Thread: jrpp-196, processing template: /home/mysite/public_html_cms/wwwroot/index.cfm, completed in 59 seconds, exceeding the 10 second warning limit"
"Warning","jrpp-214","04/25/13","15:28:56",,"Thread: jrpp-214, processing template: /home/mysite/public_html_cms/wwwroot/index.cfm, completed in 32 seconds, exceeding the 10 second warning limit"
"Warning","jrpp-134","04/25/13","15:31:53",,"Thread: jrpp-134, processing template: /home/mysite/public_html_cms/wwwroot/index.cfm, completed in 11 seconds, exceeding the 10 second warning limit"
```

Is there some way to get query string or post details in there, or is there another way to get what I'm after?

Comment: I believe Fusion Reactor will show that. http://www.fusion-reactor.com/fr/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily add some logging to your application for any requests that take longer than 10 seconds.

In onRequestStart():

```
    request.startTime = getTickCount();
```

In onRequestEnd():

```
    request.endTime = getTickCount();

    if (request.endTime - request.startTime > 10000){
        writeLog(cgi.QUERY_STRING);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing a Mach-II, FW/1 or ColdBox application, it's trivial to write a "plugin" that runs on every request which captures the URL or FORM variables passed in the request and stores that in a simple database table or log file. (You can even capture session.userID or IP address or whatever you may need.) If you're capturing to a database table, you'll probably not want any indexes to optimize for performance and you'll need to rotate that table so you're not trying to do high-speed inserts on a table with tens of millions of rows.

- In Mach-II, you'd write a plugin.
- In FW/1, you'd put a call to a controller which handles this into setupRequest() in your application.cfc.
- In ColdBox, you'd write an interceptor.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that the log just tells you what pages arw xonsostently slow sp ypu can do your own performance tuning.
Turn on debugging for further details for a start.